# Ratios of Hameitz-to-Other for Deriving Benefit

Tags: halacha, chametz-leaven, bitul-batel-null, hanaah-benefit

For the prohibition on deriving benefit from hameitz on passover, what is the ratio of hameitz-to-other that makes a mixture hameitz? I am aware that when it comes to the prohibition of eating hameitz on passover, any amount of hameitz, no matter how small, makes the whole mixture prohibited. My question is whether that applies to the prohibition of deriving benefit from hameitz in ways other than eating it (איסור הנאה) or whether there is another ratio used in that case.

Comment: if it is totally inedible even for animals it is not considered chametz. e.g. ink (other than writing on eggs), cleaning products for surfaces not used directly with food...

Comment: @CashCow - Yes, I mean to ask about food mixtures, i.e., mixtures of food that is hameitz with food that is not.