# How much beer/whisky would one have to consume to be chayav m’doaraisa?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, chametz-leaven, liquor-beer, deorayta

How much beer/whisky would one have to consume to be chayav m’doaraisa?

Also why biblically is there a prohibition on liquid chometz if it’s in the form of a liquid and not leavened bread? We know by other areas of kashrut once you break it down or change the form then on a biblical level it’s no longer the same entity. We find this concept by rennet/gelatin. I’m not saying any of this is allowed as far as Halacha l’masseh.

Comment: This depends from the suggia of kezsyit bichde achilat pras

Comment: See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/70116/9215    and the two answers, will be helpful and you will found the answer

Answer (score 1):

The Rambam writes ([MT Chametz u Matza 1:1](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/937300/jewish/Chametz-UMatzah-Chapter-One.htm))

> **Anyone who intentionally eats an olive's size of
> chametz on Pesach [...] is liable for *kareit*** [...] [The above
> **applies**] equally **to** one who eats chametz and **one who converts it into
> a liquid and drinks it.**

So the question becomes how much whiskey contains an olive's worth of barley. According to [this site](https://www.connosr.com/grain-to-whisky-ratio-question-whisky-discussion-1099), it takes roughly one kilo of barley to produce one bottle of 70cl of whisky. If you believe an olive is 27cm3 ([Wikipedia](https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Reference_of_Measurements_in_Halacha#Kezayit)), which for barley converts into 16.2 grams (according to [this site](https://www.aqua-calc.com/calculate/volume-to-weight)), then **an olive's worth of barley is 1.13cl of whiskey** (16.2 grams * 70 cl of whiskey / 1000 grams of barley).

As to your second question, of why there is a prohibition on liquid chametz, the Gemara in [Chulin 120a](https://www.sefaria.org/Chullin.120a.21?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en) says

> Reish Lakish said: One is liable even for drinking leavened bread. The
> verse states: “For all who eat leavened bread from the first day until
> the seventh day, that soul shall be cut off from Israel” (Exodus
> 12:15). The term “soul” is interpreted homiletically to include in the
> prohibition one who drinks leavened bread.

Now all is to be *chayav m’doaraisa*. As is well known, one if forbidden to consume *chametz* on Pesach in minute quantities, as the Radbaz (quoted at the end [here](https://www.etzion.org.il/en/prohibitions-chametz)) nicely explains

> Therefore, I rely upon that which the Rabbis taught that **chametz
> symbolizes the “evil inclination,”** the “se’or she-be-issa.” **Therefore,
> a person should utterly banish it from his midst and search for it in
> all of the inner chambers of his consciousness, as even the smallest
> amount is not nullified.** And this is true and correct.